# How do I connect my dots with geom_line()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple df and made a plot with the desired colors and dots, but I cannot find the solution to connect the dots with a line.

```
df <- data.frame(Cluster = rep(1:3,3), 
                 FS = c(rep("FS_1", 3), rep("FS_2", 3), rep("FS_3", 3)), 
                 Means = c(-8.9, 5.0, 1.4, -4.7, 6.8, -2.5, 3.1, -3.1, 0.6))

ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = FS, y = Means, color = factor(Cluster), group = 1)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image: Dots]

Now I want the dots connected with the same color as the dots, but with:

```
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = FS, y = Means, color = factor(Cluster), group = 1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

I get very strange lines like this:

[image: lines]

I tried to search on SO but there so much about ggplot2 that just don't seem to address my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `group = factor(Cluster)` instead of `group = 1`.

Comment: Kath, thanks!!! Conor, my code is fully reproducible, please try? I understand the downvote, sorry, but I really couldn't find it. Thank you both!